Load app inside the taskbar kind of like windows search option
I would like to get an app to load into the Taskbar of Windows 10. Just a simple Search input and Go button:

I can get it to align on top of the Taskbar in the center, but no idea what would let me add this inside the Taskbar.   I have read a lot about making a band? Or editing it.

In Windows 10, you can still implement a DeskBand for this task.  But this feature was removed in Windows 11, with no replacement. IOW, it is not possible to put custom app UIs directly onto the Windows 11+ Taskbar anymore, unless you hack/replace the Taskbar.

then i guess on top of the task bar is going to have to be ok,  as the other half of pcs are Windows 11.

"on top" is not flexible enough - taskbars can also be on the top, left or right, not just on the bottom.
